# How to use a double function as a parameter for another one?

Tags: java, function, double, function-parameter

**Hello!** I'm writing a code and one function needs to use another function as a parameter.

**My Code**

```
public static double func(double a, double b, double f(double c))
{
    return f(a)*f(b)
    
}
```

How do I make it work (Eclipse says everything is bad)?

***Thank you!***

Comment: You cannot pass methods as parameters in Java. There are many other ways to achieve versions of this behaviour, such as polymorphism via interfaces, but you probably need to explain what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually, you can pass Method instances (java.lang.reflect package) and then execute them.

Comment: @akuzminykh I know it is not optimal, and reflection has serious performance issues, but it is still a possibility to consider. We can't decide which option is best for the unique needs of the post owner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [`DoubleFunction<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/DoubleFunction.html) (or even better [`DoubleUnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleUnaryOperator.html))

```
public static double func(double a, double b, DoubleFunction<Double> f) {
  return f.apply(a) * f.apply(b);
}
```

and to call it

```
func(2, 2, d -> d + 1); // 9.
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! (Used DoubleUnaryOperator)